# How to make all instances of a template function friends of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, friend-function

I have a class which is meant to be constructed only by some factory functions and not directly.

These factory function all have the same name, but are differentiated based on the enum value passed as their template argument (see the first method explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467606/6245072)).

An example of those functions:

```
enum Tag {
    foo,
    bar,
    tag3
};

//declarations
template <Tag>
myClass Factory(int, char);

template <Tag>
myClass Factory(std::string, float);

//definitions
template <>
myClass Factory<foo>(int x, char y) {...}

template <>
myClass Factory<bar>(std::string x, float y) {...}

//as you can see, this way I can have functions with the same
//arguments that do different things with different tags:
template <>
myClass Factory<tag3>(int x, char y) {...}
```

How can I make all those functions friends of the class all at once so that they can use its private constructor?

I.e. in the example above I would want to have both `Factory<foo>`, `Factory<bar>` and `Factory<tag3>` to have access to myClass's private members, but I don't want to list each of those. How can I do it?

Comment: Any reason you can't make a myClassDeleter in your factory, and then just make that the friend?

Comment: @UKMonkey what is that supposed to do? Delete _what_?

Comment: Sorry - misread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a function template or a class template friends with your class:

```
template<class T>
class foo;

// forward declaration of the function. not really needed
template<class T>
void fun(T);

class myclass
{
private:
    int a;

    template<class T> friend class foo;
    template<class T> friend void fun(T); 
    // the above line declares foo<T>(T) to be friend of myclass
};

// the specializations definitions follow below
template<> void fun<int>(int i)
{
    myclass m;
    m.a = i; 
}

template<> void fun<char>(char c)
{
    myclass m;
    m.a = int(c);
}
// as you can see, they both can use the private members of myclass.
```

Comment: But do I have to list every operator overloading like in the `//declarations` section above? I think I'll change strategy then. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @user6245072 No, the friend declarations in my answer introduce all template specializations as friends. You don't have to list them all. If you're having trouble getting the syntax down, edit the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I meant I would have to write both `friend myClass Factory(int, char);` and `friend myClass Factory(std::string, float);`, i.e. one for each operator overloading.

Comment: @user6245072 Nope. I'll edit the answer, hope it becomes clearer.

Comment: Did you read the question? I don't have `fun<char>(char)` and `fun<int>(int)`, but rather `fun<1>(char)`, `fun<2>(int)` and `fun<3>(char)`.